# Change background color of terminal emulator wrapper

Tags: xterm

I installed a ubuntu 16.4.1 command-line version from the [minimal cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). Then I installed `x-server`. The command `x-terminal-emulator` is linked to the wrapper `/usr/bin/lxterm` of `xterm`.

Now I want to have my own back- and foreground color if I run `lxterm` or `x-terminal-emulator`. If I create the `~/.Xdefaults` file which contains the color properties it does not affect the program call `lxterm` or `x-terminal-emulator` after restarting x-server. It only affects `xterm`. How setup those properties for `lxterm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line parameters options of xterm work with lxterm for me:

```
lxterm -fg beige -bg '#2b2c2b' -fa default -fs 12 -geometry 80x4
```

[image]

Would this method work for you (using a script or putting the text string in a desktop file).

Comment: You mean to replace the symbolic link /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator with file containing `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -fg beige -bg '#2b2c2b'`? Where `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` is the result of `readlink /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`. Can i prompt replace the symbolic link in that way?

Comment: You can 'move the symbolic link to a different name' and *try*. If it does not work well for you, you can remove 'this thing', and move back the symbolic link.

Comment: But then I have the problem, if I am using the command `lxterm` or `xterm` it starts a terminal with different colors.

Comment: It is your choice if you want to use this method :-)

Comment: Sry for my stupid question. I can't reproduce the issue. Now the configurations in `.Xdefaults` achieve the `xterm` independently if I execute `xterm` or `x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: Maybe an upgrade of some program package solved your problem. (There was a problem, and you asked for a solution. Asking a question is not stupid. Sometimes the person asking and the person answering do not understand each other, but that is another problem,  that can often be solved with patience or with help from somebody else.)